# Difference between SDL_Scancode and SDL_Keycode

Tags: sdl

I am in a learning process of SDL library by version 2.0.
When I checked out SDL_Event handling , I got two different representations for keyboard event.

> **SDL_Scancode**
>
> **SDL_Keycode**

I could not understand the difference between them.Despite trying.

**What are those differences ?** and **Why are those as amount two ?**

Comment: From what I understand, keycodes are affected by the current layout, while scancodes represent physical key locations. Because of that you usually want to use scancodes for game controls.

Comment: What do you mean by " current layout "?

Comment: QWERTY vs AZERTY vs ... . For example, on an AZERTY keyboard, `Z` should have `Z` keycode and `W` scancode.

Answer (score 6):

According to the SDL wiki:
"The scancode identifies the location of a key press and the corresponding SDL_Keycode gives that key press meaning in the context of the current keyboard layout. "

So as mentioned in the comments by @HolyBlackCat if you are using a QWERTY keyboard they will be the same, but if using an AZERTY keyboard `Z` should have `Z` keycode and `W` scancode

Links to relevant parts of SDL Wiki:

[SDL_Scancode](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Scancode)

[SDL_Keycode](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Keycode)